# javascript consonants to lowercase

Tags: javascript, lowercase

Hello guys I think the following code should work but it doesn't and I don't know why, any suggestions?

It receives an array with numbers and letters and returns it with lowercase consonants. Numbers remain unchanged
Example: `consonantstoLowerCase([1,5,7,'a','J','p','E'])` returns `[1,5,7,'a','j',p,'E']`

```js
function consonantstoLowerCase( array )
{

 var result = array.toString().replace(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/g, function (char) 
 {
     return char.toLowerCase();
 });

 console.log(result)
 
}
```

OUTPUT:

`consonantstoLowerCase([1,5,7,'a','J','p','E'])`  =>  `1,5,7,a,J,p,E`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are only looking for lowercase in your reg exp. `a` for not match `A`

Comment: To make the regex case insensitive add `i` to it, ex: `/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/ig` but you should only look for uppercase consonants, `/[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]/g`

Comment: Also, you are returning a comma-separated string, not an array as requested. You would need to `.split(",")` again, but this will break when you are passed commas. You should probably use `array.map()` and perform the replacement there if the item is an uppercase letter.

Comment: Did you forget the A or is it on purpose?

Comment: @Titus answer of /ig worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
consonantstoLowerCase([1,5,7,'a','J','p','E','k','m','I'])
function consonantstoLowerCase( array )
{

 var result = array.toString().replace(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/ig, function (char) 
 {
     return char.toLowerCase();
 });

 console.log(result)
 
}
```

Comment: Why voting down for a code giving proper answer? Just test the snippet ;)

Answer (score 0):

To get the array you want, just map the values, check if they match a consonant, and if so, return them `toLowerCase()`. (Also mind the `i` modifier on the matcher - now we're checking for uppercase letters too, like you want...).

Ahh, and because it's les to write, I check for not matching vocals and numbers...

```js
var input = [1,5,7,'a','J','p','E'];

function consonantToLowerCase(arr) {
  var vocals = /[aeiou0-9]/ig;  
  return arr.map(function(e) {
    if (! e.toString().match(vocals)) return e.toLowerCase();
    return e;
  });  
}

console.log(consonantToLowerCase(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
var arr = [1,5,7,'a','J','p','E'];
arr = arr.map(e => /[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]/g.test(e) ? e.toLowerCase() : e);
console.log(arr);
```

In response to your comment, to change consonants to lower case and vowels to upper case, you can do something like this:

```js
var arr = [1,5,7,'a','J','p','E'];
arr = arr.map(function(e){
    e = /[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]/g.test(e) ? e.toLowerCase() : e;
    e = /[aeiou]/g.test(e) ? e.toUpperCase() : e;
    return e;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: What's the difference with your previous answer of adding the final ig:

/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/ig

I think it's more DRY, isn't it?

Comment: @Defoe You only need to modify upper case consonants so it is not necessary to look for lower case ones since they should remain unmodified. Also, this example returns an `Array` instead of a `String`.

Comment: ok actually that was one part of the exercise. I did the vowels part on my own but the entire exercise is this:

//It receives an array with numbers and letters and returns it with uppercase vowels and lowercase consonants. Numbers remain unchanged
 //Example: beautifyLetters([1,5,7,'a','J','p','E']) returns [1,5,7,'A','j',p,'E']

How can I combine it all together?

Comment: I don't know how to edit your answer but it gave the error unexpected token ) because it needs to be });   at the end. Despite that fact it worked like charm, thanks lots!

Comment: can you edit it yourself so I can click to the tick icon? Thanks